# Max Posts and Memory Limit

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

So I have a custom post type which uses ACF Metaboxes that contains over 750 posts and grwoing.  I got the infamous white screen of death because it seems like PHP has exhaused it's memory limit querying all these posts and data.  I set my PHP.INI file's max execution time and memory limit to `-1` and increased my WP's memory limit in config to `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '4096M');`

yet I'm still receiving a white screen of death in the admin when trying to view the custom post type.  Any ideas on how to fix/increase memory?

Thanks

Comment: Are you fetching 750 posts at once. Is that really necessary? Profile your page. I wonder how many db queries you got on each page load.

Comment: I should clarify, you're right.  When I query lest posts on the front end, it's all good.  It's the admin post type view where I'm having the problem, fore example: `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=books`

Comment: Do you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled in `wp-config.php`? What makes you think that PHP is exhausting it's memory limit; do you know this for sure or are you guessing?

Comment: This is the errpr: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1941`

Comment: Alright, that's a good start - it appears to be crapping out in the `$wpdb->get_results()` method, which could well indicate that some query is returning an obscure amount of data. Do you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled in `wp-config.php`? I would also enable `WP_DEBUG_LOG` so any errors get logged into the `wp-content` directory. Any WordPress-generated errors or warnings show up? I feel like this may have something to do with the internals of ACF Metaboxes which I'm entirely unfamiliar with, so I'm not sure how much more help I will be...

Comment: As @birgie suggested, profiling the page load would prove to be a large step in troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was happening b/c of post meta cache issues. This article suggested code which solved my issue - and apparently many other's as well.

https://junaid.dev/wordpress-admin-fix-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-error/?unapproved=369&moderation-hash=bd9064ea40d413150d8a42599c13f4f5#comment-369

Here is the code he provides:

```
function jb_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $wp_query ) {
    if ( in_array( $wp_query->get( 'post_type' ), array( 'my_post_type_1', 'my_post_type_2' ) ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'update_post_meta_cache', false );
    }
}

// Only do this for admin.
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'jb_pre_get_posts' );
}
```